# I have an app which I would like to test based on following criteria for around 40 countries

Tags: testing, mobile, proxy, localization

I have an app which I would like to test based on following criteria for around 40 countries:

- commonly used mobile devices in each region / country
- the prominent service providers in each region / country
- the type of bandwidth available in each region / country

Countries like:
Canada  North America
Bermuda North America
Russia  Europe
Spain   Europe
Turkey  Europe
Poland  Europe
Netherlands Europe
Romania Europe
Sweden  Europe

I would like to know whether there is any application that provide such support?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of companies that provide remote testing service along the lines I think you are looking for, for example:

- http://www.perfectomobile.com/content/platform
- http://www.keynote.com/solutions/testing/mobile-testing

You will probably need to contact them to see if they meet your particular country requirements etc and you might have to use multiple providers to get the coverage you are looking for.

See also this similar question from a few years ago:

[Remote Test Laboratory for Mobile App testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13525256/remote-test-laboratory-for-mobile-app-testing)